# Query in Controller from ID with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, laravel, datatables

I'm trying to get data form a database table from an ID and show it in a datatable.

With jQuery, I have the next function:

```
var info = function(tbody, table){
$(tbody).on("click","a[id=ButtonMas]", function(){
        if(table.row(this).child.isShown()){
            var data = table.row(this).data();
        }else{
            var data = table.row($(this).parents("tr")).data();
        }

        var pc = data["id"];
        route = "/historico/"+pc+"";

        $('#ModalInfoEquipos').modal('show');

        var dt_historico = $('#t_historico').DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": route,
                "dataSrc": ""
                },
            "columns": [
                { "data": "created_at" },
                { "data": "estado" },
                { "data": "ubicacion" },
                { "data": "empleado" },
                { "data": "f_asignacion" },                    ],
            "language": {
                    "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/9dcbecd42ad/i18n/Spanish.json"
                },
            "scrollX": true,
        });
});
}
```

In my Controller, I've implemented the next index:

```
public function index(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $historico = HistoricoEquipos::Consulta($id);
        return response()->json($historico);
    }
    return view('historico.index');
}
```

But my response->json get is empty an incorrect.

In my Model, I've implemented my function Consulta:

```
public static function Consulta($id){
    return DB::table('historico_equipos')
        ->select('historico_equipos.*')
        ->where('id_equipo', $id)
        ->get();
}
```

I get the next request and need to take the first value(1) for my query:

[Request - Chrome Inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vheDW.png)

Where is the error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have an error in my route definition.

I've changed this:

```
Route::resource('historico','HistoricoEquiposController')
```

To this:

```
Route::resource('historico','HistoricoEquiposController', ['except' =>['index']]);
Route::get('historico/{historico}', 'HistoricoEquiposController@index')->name('historico.index');
```

With help of @Shaz. Thanks.